# How to find vertices on the longest border of a SurfaceMesh in CGAL

Tags: border, mesh, cgal

I want to use CGAL to mark the longest border of a mesh of type `SurfaceMesh`. 
I know there exists a function `CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::longest_border` but it only gives a `halfedge_descriptor`, which the documentation says **is a part of this border**. So how to get all the vertices or halfedges of this longest border.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like that:

```
halfedge_descriptor hd = CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::longest_border(mesh);
halfedge_descriptor start = hd;
do
{
  //store hd 
  hd = next(hd, mesh);
}while hd != start;
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining the above answers, the following answer prints the list of all vertices index lying on longest border (& also saves a vector of index). For simplicity, includes are ignored:

```
typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double>    Kernel;
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh<Kernel::Kernel::Point_3>  SurfaceMesh;
typedef boost::graph_traits<SurfaceMesh>::halfedge_descriptor  halfedge_descriptor;
typedef SurfaceMesh::Vertex_index  mesh_vertex_descriptor;

boost::filesystem::path in;
SurfaceMesh sm;
std::vector<int> borderVertexID;
in >> sm;
bhd = CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::longest_border(sm).first;
BOOST_FOREACH(mesh_vertex_descriptor ved, vertices_around_face(bhd,sm)){
    std::cout << ved << std::endl;
    borderVertexID.push_back(ved);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

And instead of the loop with `next()` you can also write

`for(vertex_descriptor : CGAL::vertices_around_face(hd, mesh){
 // do something
}`

See the [manual](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/BGL/group__PkgBGLIterators.html#ga7746cb7b28520877375dfff6ec7bd32c)